# AWS TLS Security profile "FS-1-2-Res-2020-10" documentation states 4 ciphers but a scan only returns 2. Is AWS documentation stale?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

The documentation for **FS-1-2-Res-2020-10** found in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html shows four different Ciphers, however, the ones with no asterisk appended do not appear in TLS cipher scans (TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 and TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)

PROFILE # FS-1-2-Res-2020-10

aws documentation:

- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (missing)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (match)
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (missing)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (match)

What a cipher scan returns:

- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (match)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (match)

My scans should have returned a total of four ciphers similar to what AWS documentation states what comes with the security profile

Comment: If you have an RSA certificate you can use RSA ciphersuites. If you have an ECDSA certificate you can use ECDSA ciphersuites.